# Groupby value and return index

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use linq to group the data using value and to return the corresponding indexes as array.

**Example**

```
int[] input = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2}
```

**Expected output**

```
Dictionary<int,int[]> ouput = {0->[0,1,2,3,8,9,10,11]; 1 -> [4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15]; 2 -> [16,17,18,19]}
```

Can anybody guide me?

Comment: hm.. what is a logic of pick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var output = input.Select((x, i) => new { Value=x, Index=i })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Index)
                                                  .ToArray());
```

This first selects an anonymous type to save the original index in the array, then groups by the value and afterwards transforms the grouped result into a dictionary with the key of each group as the key of the dictionary and from all elements in the corresponding group the index is selected.

A shorter way would be this:

```
var output2 = input.Select((x, i) => new { Value=x, Index=i })
                   .ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);
```

This would result in a `Lookup<int, int>` which is semantically the same as the `Dictionary<int, int[]>`.

Comment: what it is a logic behind the data aggregation?

Comment: @Tigran: Which aggregation do you mean? Maybe it already is answered in the extended answer?

Comment: may I'm just tired, wasn't able understand what OP's actually asking for.. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = input
            .Select((i, index) => new{Num=i, Index=index})
            .GroupBy(x => x.Num)
            .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! nice to see you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
input.Select( (i, index) => new {Value = i, Index = index})
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(y => new { Key = y.Key, Indexes = y.Select(z => z.Index).ToList() });
```

Comment: will this produce expected result?

Comment: @Tigran: This returns the correct result but not as dictionary but as `IEnumerable<Anonymous Type>`.